# How can I use value of a string to control another control in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have been playing around with some code, and I have made easily 50+ controls that all are labeled: `PictureBox[XCoordinate]_[YCorrdinate]` (Replacing the brackets and contents with the coordinates of them on a little grid I made.)

The problem with this is it is a real pain to use a control when doing loops to update all the picture boxes. I want to know how to do code like:

```
'This code assumes that the picture boxes are all initialized.
Dim XCoordiante As Integer = 5
Dim YCorrdinate As Integer = 2
PictureBox[XCoordinate]_[YCoordiante].Image = [Put Image Here]
```

**I am going to put this within a loop. Is there a way that I can do this without manually typing it all and risking missing something within a case statement? And also, I would have to retype it for every different kind of change I want to make (ex: tag or error image).**

Would a pointer somehow help? I don't really know how to do this, but it would be really helpful if possible.

Comment: What is the upper limits of your X and Y coordinates?

Comment: `Me.controls("picturebox" & XCoordiante.Tostring & "_" & YCorrdinate.Tostring").Image = ...`  You might be better off saving them to a List(Of PictureBox) and just zip thru the list perhaps keying off the .Location or a .Tag value.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Not very high; 1 <= X <= 8 and 1 <= Y <= 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create them, save them to a List:

```
Private pList As New List(Of PictureBox)

Dim pic As New PictureBox
With Pic
    .Location = ... 
    ' etc
End With

Me.Controls.Add(pic)
pList.Add(pic)
```

Assuming they are created in some sort of order:

```
For n As integer = 0 To pList.Count = 1
   ' add code to look at Plist(n).X and .Y to determine what to do (?)
   Plist(n).Image = ...
Next n
```

If there is more info to capture, create a custom class of a `PicBox` and the other info, and make the list a `List(Of myPicClass)`.